# How to redraw text on gradient background in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using python 2.7.1 with pygame 1.9.1 on 64-bit win7.  I am using the gradient code from http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GradientCode to draw my background.  I then display text like so:

```
countText = font.render( "%d" % secs_left, 1, (255, 0, 0))
countRect = countText.get_rect()
countRect.y, countRect.centerx = yPos, screen.get_rect().width/2
screen.blit(countText, countRect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

I use this to display a countdown timer, but the problem is the numbers draw on top of one another.  I can specify a background color in the font.render() call that will solve this, but then I get another problem where the solid background doesn't match the gradient background.

I think this can be solved by saving a copy of the gradient background in another surface, and then drawing the relevant portion of the saved surface onto the background before drawing the next number, but I am not sure how to do this.

I can save a copy of the gradient background like this:

```
# save a surface with same size and gradient as background
bg_image = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
fill_gradient(bg_image, BG_COLOR, GRADIENT_COLOR)
```

But how do I select the relevant portion of bg_image and draw it to my main screen background?  I tried something like this, doing a screen.blit() to try and erase the current countdown number before blitting the new number, but it doesn't work:

```
countText = usefont.render( "%d" % secs_left, 1, (255, 0, 0))
countRect = countText.get_rect()
countRect.y, countRect.centerx = yPos, screen.get_rect().width/2
screen.blit(bg_image, (0,0), countRect)
screen.blit(countText, countRect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Would this be the best approach (with code that works)?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use Surface.set_clip() to restrict the area being updated to just the rectangle containing the countdown text:

```
countText = usefont.render( "%d" % secs_left, 1, (255, 0, 0))
countRect = countText.get_rect()
countRect.y, countRect.centerx = yPos, screen.get_rect().width/2
screen.set_clip(countRect)        # Allow updates only to area in countRect
screen.blit(bg_image, (0,0))      # bg_img will only be drawn within countRect
screen.blit(countText, countRect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

- use `pygame.display.set_mode(size, 0, 32)` to get your screen surface, it supports transparent.
- Use a surface to save your background, we name it `bg_surface`
- You get a new text surface every time you do `font.render`, name it `txt_surface`
- When each time before `pygame.display.flip()`, blit the `bg_surface` and then `txt_surface` to `screen`.

It's that what you need? If you are rendering a counter, it's enougth to blit the whole background every frame.

Comment: This will erase everything when blitting bg_surface.  I want to erase just the countdown text area.  I have other stuff on the screen, not just the countdown text.

Comment: Then you could use `Surface.subsurface(rect)` method to get only part of `bg_surface`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post while researching a minor variation of the same question.  Here is a running generic solution created after combining information from various places.  In this case, the bg_image can be used directly, since the title that is (also) placed on top does not overlap with the count.  I used a different method of generating the gradient, but that is not important.  Especially when using `screen.copy()` to create a reference surface to use during the restore.

```py
#!python3

import os
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

size = 640, 480
pygame.init()
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, NOFRAME, 0)
width, height = screen.get_size()
pygame.event.set_blocked(MOUSEMOTION)  # keep our queue cleaner

# build gradient background
colors = np.random.randint(0, 255, (2, 3))
topcolor = np.array(colors[0], copy=0)
bottomcolor = np.array(colors[1], copy=0)
diff = bottomcolor - topcolor
column = np.arange(height, dtype=np.float32) / height  # create array from 0.0 to 1.0 triplets
column = np.repeat(column[:, np.newaxis], [3], 1)
column = topcolor + (diff * column).astype(np.int)  # create a single column of gradient
column = column.astype(np.uint8)[np.newaxis, :, :]  # make column a 3d image column by adding X
column = pygame.surfarray.map_array(screen, column)  # 3d array into 2d array
gradient = np.resize(column, (width, height))  # stretch the column into a full image

bg_image = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(gradient)
screen.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))

usefont = pygame.font.Font(None, 144)
# add content that does not get erased with the count down value
title_surf = usefont.render('Counting…', True, (200, 100, 50))
title_rect = title_surf.get_rect()
title_rect.topleft = (20, 5)
screen.blit(title_surf, title_rect)
pygame.display.flip()

savedSurface = screen.copy()  # when no convenient surface to restore from

pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000)
screen_center = int(width / 2), int(height / 2)
savedRect = screen_center, (0, 0)  # First time, nothing to restore
secs_left = 11
while secs_left > 0:
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type in (QUIT, KEYDOWN, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):
        break
    if event.type == USEREVENT:
        # screen.blit(bg_image, savedRect, savedRect)  # restore background
        screen.blit(savedSurface, savedRect, savedRect)  # restore background
        secs_left -= 1
        countText = usefont.render('%d' % secs_left, 1, (255, 0, 0))
        countRect = countText.get_rect()
        countRect.center = screen_center
        savedRect = screen.blit(countText, countRect)
        pygame.display.flip()
```